# Reporting Services Deployment

Tags: deployment, reporting-services

I need to create a repeatable process for deploying SQL Server Reporting Services reports.  I am not in favor of using Visual Studio and or Business Development Studio to do this.  The rs.exe method of scripting deployments also seems rather clunky.  Does anyone have a very elegant way that they have been able to deploy reports. The key here is that I want the process to be completely automated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We use rs.exe, once we developed the script we have not needed to touch it anymore, it just works.

Here is the source (I slightly modified it by hand to remove sensitive data without a chance to test it, hope I did not brake anything), it deploys reports and associated images from subdirectories for various languages. Also datasource is created.

```
'=====================================================================
'  File:      PublishReports.rss
'
'  Summary: Script that can be used with RS.exe to 
'           publish the reports.
'
'  Rss file spans from beginnig of this comment to end of module
' (except of "End Module").
'=====================================================================

Dim langPaths As String() = {"en", "cs", "pl", "de"}
Dim filePath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory

Public Sub Main()

    rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    'Create parent folder
    Try
        rs.CreateFolder(parentFolder, "/", Nothing)
        Console.WriteLine("Parent folder created: {0}", parentFolder)
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

    PublishLanguagesFromFolder(filePath)

End Sub

Public Sub PublishLanguagesFromFolder(ByVal folder As String)
    Dim Lang As Integer
    Dim langPath As String

    For Lang = langPaths.GetLowerBound(0) To langPaths.GetUpperBound(0)
        langPath = langPaths(Lang)

        'Create the lang folder
        Try
            rs.CreateFolder(langPath, "/" + parentFolder, Nothing)
            Console.WriteLine("Parent lang folder created: {0}", parentFolder + "/" + langPath)
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try

        'Create the shared data source
        CreateDataSource("/" + parentFolder + "/" + langPath)

        'Publish reports and images
        PublishFolderContents(folder + "\" + langPath, "/" + parentFolder + "/" + langPath)
    Next 'Lang
End Sub

Public Sub CreateDataSource(ByVal targetFolder As String)
    Dim name As String = "data source"

    'Data source definition.
    Dim definition As New DataSourceDefinition
    definition.CredentialRetrieval = CredentialRetrievalEnum.Store
    definition.ConnectString = "data source=" + dbServer + ";initial catalog=" + db
    definition.Enabled = True
    definition.EnabledSpecified = True
    definition.Extension = "SQL"
    definition.ImpersonateUser = False
    definition.ImpersonateUserSpecified = True
    'Use the default prompt string.
    definition.Prompt = Nothing
    definition.WindowsCredentials = False
    'Login information
    definition.UserName = "user"
    definition.Password = "password"

    Try
    'name, folder, overwrite, definition, properties 
        rs.CreateDataSource(name, targetFolder, True, definition, Nothing)
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub PublishFolderContents(ByVal sourceFolder As String, ByVal targetFolder As String)
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder)
    Dim fis As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim fi As FileInfo

    Dim fileName As String

    For Each fi In fis
        fileName = fi.Name
        Select Case fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 4).ToUpper
            Case ".RDL"
                PublishReport(sourceFolder, fileName, targetFolder)
            Case ".JPG", ".JPEG"
                PublishResource(sourceFolder, fileName, "image/jpeg", targetFolder)
            Case ".GIF", ".PNG", ".BMP"
                PublishResource(sourceFolder, fileName, "image/" + fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3).ToLower, targetFolder)
        End Select
    Next fi
End Sub

Public Sub PublishReport(ByVal sourceFolder As String, ByVal reportName As String, ByVal targetFolder As String)
    Dim definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing

    Try
        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFolder + "\" + reportName)
        definition = New [Byte](stream.Length) {}
        stream.Read(definition, 0, CInt(stream.Length))
        stream.Close()
    Catch e As IOException
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

    Try
   'name, folder, overwrite, definition, properties 
        warnings = rs.CreateReport(reportName.Substring(0, reportName.Length - 4), targetFolder, True, definition, Nothing)

        If Not (warnings Is Nothing) Then
            Dim warning As Warning
            For Each warning In warnings
                Console.WriteLine(warning.Message)
            Next warning
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} published successfully with no warnings", targetFolder + "/" + reportName)
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub PublishResource(ByVal sourceFolder As String, ByVal resourceName As String, ByVal resourceMIME As String, ByVal targetFolder As String)
    Dim definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing

    Try
        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFolder + "\" + resourceName)
        definition = New [Byte](stream.Length) {}
        stream.Read(definition, 0, CInt(stream.Length))
        stream.Close()
    Catch e As IOException
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

    Try
    'name, folder, overwrite, definition, MIME, properties 
        rs.CreateResource(resourceName, targetFolder, True, definition, resourceMIME, Nothing)
        Console.WriteLine("Resource: {0} with MIME {1} created successfully", targetFolder + "/" + resourceName, resourceMIME)
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the batch to call the rs.exe:

```
SET ReportServer=%1
SET DBServer=%2
SET DBName=%3
SET ReportFolder=%4

rs -i PublishReports.rss -s %ReportServer% -v dbServer="%DBServer%" -v db="%DBName%" -v parentFolder="%ReportFolder%" >PublishReports.log 2>&1

pause
```

Comment: Hi. I was attempting to use this script for my own reporting services deployments. Question.. How do I organize the directory structure on my computer?  Do I have a vs project for each report subdirectory that I want?

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS projects. The script expects subfolder for every language mutation (eg. en, de, see script begining). Every language folder contains rdl files and resources used (typically images used by reports).

Comment: I understand that this script has nothing to do with VS projects, but I am developing my reports in visual studio, so I was wondering how to organize the directory structure of the project so that I can use this script to deploy the reports instead of the VS method.

Comment: Thanks for the script! But you have to explicitly set the data source again: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88710/reporting-services-deployment/2759212#2759212).

Answer (score 8):

I used the script [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88710/reporting-services-deployment/91077#91077) supplied but I had to add some code (I'm typing this up as an answer, as this would be too long for a comment.

The problem is: if there is already a "shared datasource" attached to a report in the report definition, this is never the same datasource as the one that is created in the script.

This also becomes apparent from the warning emitted by the "CreateReport" method:

> The data set '' refers to the shared data source '', which is not published on the report server.

So the data source has to be set explicitly afterwards. I've made the following code changes:

I added a global variable:

```
Dim dataSourceRefs(0) As DataSource
```

At the end of the CreateDataSource method, that variable gets filled:

```
Dim dsr As New DataSourceReference
dsr.Reference = "/" + parentFolder + "/" + db
Dim ds As New DataSource
ds.Item = CType(dsr, DataSourceDefinitionOrReference)
ds.Name = db
dataSourceRefs(0) = ds
```

And in the PublishReport method, that data source gets explicitly set (after CreateReport has been called):

```
rs.SetItemDataSources(targetFolder + "/" + reportName.Substring(0, reportName.Length - 4), dataSourceRefs)
```

Note that this last call is only RS 2005 or higher. If you want to load your reports onto a RS 2000 server, you have to use Set*Report*DataSources in stead:

```
rs.SetReportDataSources(targetFolder + "/" + reportName.Substring(0, reportName.Length - 4), dataSourceRefs)
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to fix this reference before calling CreateReport, because I want my script output to be without warnings, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Well not really elegant. We created our own tool that uses the reportingservices2005 web service. We found this to be the most reliable way of getting what we want.

It's not really that difficult and lets you expand it to do other things like creating data sources and folders as required.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [RSScripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62). As noted in the overview:

> Reporting Services Scripter is a .NET
>   Windows Forms application that enables
>   scripting and transfer of all
>   Microsoft SQL Server Reporting
>   Services catalog items to aid in
>   transferring them from one server to
>   another. It can also be used to easily
>   move items on mass from one Reporting
>   Services folder to another on the same
>   server. Depending on the scripting
>   options chosen, Reporting Services
>   Scripter can also transfer all catalog
>   item properties such as Descriptions,
>   History options, Execution options
>   (including report specific and shared
>   schedules), Subscriptions (normal and
>   data driven) and server side report
>   parameters.

Comment: unfortunately RSScripter is no longer being updated, which means it doesn't support the newer objects such as shared datasets...

Answer (score 0):

I know you say that you're not in favor of the Business Development Studio to do this, but I've found the built-in tools to be very reliable and easy to use.

Comment: Oh I agree.  The issue is that I really want the deployment to be completely automated.

Comment: ah.  we only deploy to a test and production server, and only after changes have been made, so using the buil-in tools works really well for us (lucky us, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into any Continuous Integration solutions such as CruiseControl.NET? If you are able to deploy Reports using rs.exe then you can setup an automated process in CruiseControl to build and deploy your Reports on a timer or whenever a report is modified.

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, we develop in VS with version control then deploy to DEV SSRS.  Once the report is validated, we use ReportSync program to deploy reports from `ReportServer DEV` to `ReportServer PROD`.  The RS.EXE scripts still have their place, but I have found ReportSync to be a much simpler and agile way to promote a report.

**ReportSync:**

**`ReportSync`** is an open source program free to download and use.  It works great for downloading reports in bulk, and it can even push a report from one server to another server.

---

How to get download the program?

- Download the source code files from [Github: Phires/ReportSynch](http://github.com/phires/reportsync), Run VS, Open the solution file (.SLN), compile the program, find the executable file (.EXE) from the *C:\Temp\reportsync-master\bin\Release* folder.  Finally, saved the .EXE somewhere for you to use regularly
- [How do I copy SSRS reports to a new server if I am not the owner of the reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336576/how-do-i-copy-ssrs-reports-to-a-new-server-if-i-am-not-the-owner-of-the-reports) --> ReportSync answer by nunespascal

How to deploy a report?

1. Run the executable and the interface will launch.
2. Use the `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION` dialogues to choose a `single report`, `multiple reports`, or an `entire folder of reports`.  You can any target folder you would like.  (HINT: You can even target the same server if you are wanting to duplicate a report on the same server.)
3. After making your selections press the `Sync button`
4. Go to the target server, and validate the change took effect by reviewing the Changed By Date.

This tool has been very convenient, but I have noticed some quirks.  For example `when I want to update just one report that already exists in the destination`, here is what I have to select-- [`Source:Report> Target:Folder> Sync`].  WARNING: You might think you would select the target server report to update it, but I have tried this and the report does not get updated.

---

What else can ReportSync do?

- There is also an `Export` feature, which works marvelously for simply dumping all the RDL files to a folder for me to access.  This is helpful in the event you need to migrate the server,  add the files to to a VS Solution Project, or do anything else will all the files.
- In my testing this program **does not** migrate other content-- subscriptions, shared data sources,  shared data sets.  It is just applicable to the report files.

I know this post is old, but I came across it when researching RS.EXE scripts, so I thought I would provide an answer this question.