# Auto-Deploy SSRS reports with TFS

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, reporting-services, tfs, tfsbuild

Can anyone explain how to create a custom build to deploy reporting services reports with TFS? Is it possible? If so then how...  Samples or articles will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't use TFS to do my deploy but I'm pretty sure your build could execute a batch script. Check out this post here [Reporting Services Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88710/reporting-services-deployment) for an example .rss script and batch file.

This doesn't sound exactly like what you're looking for but I hope this helps some.

Comment: You could hook up Tfs Deployer (http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/) to run that batch script, that way you don't need to customize your build definitions.