# Customizing the TFS 2008 build sequence to avoid compilation and deploy SSRS

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to create a CI process for SQL Server Reporting Services.
I am fairly new to TFS but quite experienced with MSBuild.  In the past I've used a combination of MSBuild with Team City so the whole build process is more or less custom.

Here lies the start of my problems, as the solution I am deploying only contains Report Server projects (*rds*), no compilation is required.  I thought that I would override the the first default task that TFS runs (*EndToEndIteration*) to override the default TFS build sequence and inject my own.

The first snag that I have come across is that the build always fails, how can I set the status of the build to success?  Currently the EndToEndIteration task is very light and only has a message.

Is this the best method to create a custom build process in TFS where compilation is not required?  Or should I use the default sequence and override one of the hook tasks mentioned in

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604%28VS.80%29.aspx
  (*ie: AfterCompile*)

The core steps that I'd like to achieve are:

1. Bundle the RDL and datasource files
2. Connect to the host server to
   register/deploy the reports
3. Re-apply any subscriptions that
   previously existed
4. Run tests to verify the deployment
   succeeded and is returning results
   as expected

I have found another article on Report services deployment:

- [Reporting Services Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88710/reporting-services-deployment)

But it doesn't mention the best practice for customizing the standard build process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I've just stumbled apon an answer to the first question I asked:

> The first snag that I have come across is that the build always fails, how can I set the status of the build to success?

You can find a solution to this at
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaronhallberg/how-to-fail-a-build-when-tests-fail)

The options available for this property are:

- Unknown
- Failed
- Succeeded

Don't forget to also set the TestStatus else the build will only partially succeed

Still looking for the best practice for creating a custom build sequence.