# Move SSRS Reports from one reportserver to another

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to move/copy SSRS reports from one server to another with the folder structure and, etc.?

Can I just copy what's in catalog table and add it to catalog table under a new server?

The reason I am looking for a solution like this is because there are over 200+ reports on the current reportserver with several folders, data sources and subscriptions.  I'd like to save time if that is possible.

Comment: Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531017.aspx#bkmk_supported_scenarios) utility, it could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Report Sync](http://code.google.com/p/reportsync/) - You may need to change some code if it may not work on your environment.

Use **Sync** button to update same report on different server.

Use **Upload** button to upload all selected report to particular folder on different server.

Use **Download** button to download all reports to local drive.

Please let me know, if you have any doubts/query or need any help regarding this.

Comment: This is a great tool.  However, it is a must that we inherit which users created which reports. This is because we only support reports that were created by us.  Also, it breaks data source connection.  We have 300+ reports so it is bit annoying.  Do you know any other process/tools who would accomplish this?

Comment: I'm also having 300+ reports and using same tool to deploy/sync on live server. I never get such data source connection error. I'm using hi-speed connection and you may need to change some code for time out operation. And if you're asking me for another tool then sorry I don't have any idea about same tool like this. But it is sure we can change the code as per our needs accordingly. Hope you understand what I'm saying... Have a great time and happy coding... Let me know if you need any other help. I have played on catalog database also so I may help you somewhere else also...

Answer (score 2):

You can try [reportsync tool](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reportsync/) which is needed to migrate the SSRS reports from one server to another. Give it a try. I have tested this successfully in my environment in the past.

Check this link too for more details: [SSRSReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336576/how-do-i-copy-ssrs-reports-to-a-new-server-if-i-am-not-the-owner-of-the-reports)

Hope this helps you!