# Deploying SSRS on SQL Server via tfs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2012

I want to deploy a SSRS project from a TFS server to another server (ProdServer) as a job in SQL Server and run it dynamically.

How I can do it please.

Comment: what do you mean dynamically? the dumbest way I could think of is to add all the TFS SSRS reports to your local project, then deploy that project to target server

Comment: actually i want to schedule TFS to deploy every night the work done during the day.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I am using TFS 2015

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write Batch script or use utility such as RS.exe to deploy the report, then in TFS Build definition call the script or utility.

1. Write script to deploy the report, reference [this article](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2010/03/30/how-to-deploy-a-report-rdl-file-to-sql-server-reporting-services-using-powershell/). For
   Utility reference this thread:
   [Reporting Services Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88710/reporting-services-deployment)
2. Create a Scheduled build definition and add the step
   BatchScript/Command Line/PowerShell to call the script/utility

Below threads also for your reference:

- [Best Practice for Deploying SSRS Reports](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/997ee5ad-e6bf-4c6c-8400-7a7c8bd2044b/best-practice-for-deploying-ssrs-reports?forum=tfsbuild)
- [SQL Server Reporting Services Basics: Deploying Reports](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-basics-deploying-reports/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is new form me working on scripts. I will notice if I succeeded.